# change image border color onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, border

I have a page where the users needs to pick a color for a tshirt.

When the user selects a color, I want the image's border color to change to green.

And if the user click a different color, it needs to put back the default border color and change the border color of the new image that was clicked.

Any idea how I could do that ?

Comment: It seems to be working already. What's the problem?

Comment: it is indeed working on your website you linked.

Comment: The website i linked to is just an example of what i want to do..

Comment: I ended up finding exactly what i needed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374393/on-click-img-border-color-multiple-images-only-need-1-highlighted-at-a-ti?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Say your image is displayed using `img` tag as below:

```
  <img name="img01" id="img01" src="image.gif" border="2" bordercolor="#000000">
```

implement onClick fnction `fnChangeBorder` as below

```
   function fnChangeBorder(){
      document.getElementById("img01").style.borderColor="#00FF00";
   }
```

or

```
   function fnChangeBorder(){
      var imgElement = document.getElementById("img01");
      imgElement.setAttribute("style:borderColor", "#00FF00");
   }
```

or you can define a style class and do like:

```
   function fnChangeBorder(){
      document.getElementById("img01").style.className="greenClass";
   }
```

EDIT:

For multiple images, with indexed id, we can pass the index in the onclick function as:

```
  <img name="img1" id="img1" src="image.gif" border="2" bordercolor="#000000"
        onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(1);">

  <img name="img2" id="img2" src="image.gif" border="2" bordercolor="#000000"
        onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(2);">
```

And update `fnChangeBorder` as:

```
   function fnChangeBorder(index){
      document.getElementById("img"+index).style.className="greenClass";
   }
```

For multiple images, with non-indexed id, we can pass the `id` in the onclick function as:

```
  <img name="imgabc" id="imgabc" src="image.gif" border="2" bordercolor="#000000"
        onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder('imgabc`);">

  <img name="imgxyz" id="imgxyz" src="image.gif" border="2" bordercolor="#000000"
        onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder('imgxyz');">
```

And update `fnChangeBorder` as:

```
   function fnChangeBorder(imageId){
      document.getElementById(imageId).style.className="greenClass";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But since i have a dozen of images, i would need a dozen of functions like this for each images ? 
And like i said, if the user clicks another image it needs to set all images to default border color and set the green border color only for this one..

Comment: Not really. I didn't get the idea earlier that you have dozen of images. I hope you are trying to update one at a time. There are more ways. I am updating the answer with first two ways to manage. Please let me know, if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Create one class with your styles. For example

```
.selected{
   border : 1px solid green;
}
```

Then apply the className on click of the item. Avoid using setAttribute to set Class name of a item. It is having some issues. Then onclick of the image remove the selected class name on all items and then apply class name selected to the target image.